# Performing ajax with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to do something simple yet not able to figure it out because of no experience working with scripting languages and even after going through some tutorials. The closest match to what I want to kind of do is found at this  [link](http://code.runnable.com/UiPhLHanceFYAAAP/how-to-perform-ajax-in-flask-for-python) .

When someone clicks on the following link I want value attribute to be returned to the same template that this link I'm creating is in so I can use it for an array's index argument.

```
<a href="/disable?server={{count + loop.index0}}" 
id="serverCount" 
value="{{ count + loop.index0 }}">
Click this to Disable </a>
```

The JavaScript/json/ajax I have is:

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $('a#serverCount').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/disable', {
      a: document.getElementById("serverCount").getAttribute("value")
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm sure someone will be able to realize what I have definitely does not work. I'm just posting the code I've been experimenting with.

In app.py I have:

```
@app.route('/disable', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def disableBtn():
    valueOfButton = request.args.get['serverCount']
    return jsonify(result = valueOfButton)
```

Can someone explain what the correct way of doing this will be? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using jQuery why not go the simple jQuery way of getting the value?

```
$('#serverCount').val();
```

So typically when I make an ajax call where I'm expecting JSON data back and I'm sending JSON to the server.  I would do something like this;

```
$(function() {
    $('a#serverCount').bind('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/url/to/your/server/method",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { serverCount: $('#serverCount').val() }
            })
            .done(function(msgBackFromServer) {
                alert("Data Sent to server" + msgBackFromServer);
            });
    });
});
```

now you'll notice the url needs to be a method that can be hit on your server, some sort or page view that you have.  I'm not familiar in Flask, but I would imagine it's similar to Django in some ways.

Method POST is because your sending data.  On your flask server, you should be able to receive JSON and parse it into a Python dictionary (or maybe there is some other flask specific tool).

Your response from this view is what is passed back to the .done function of the ajax call.  This could be whatever data you want it to be.  It will come from flask.  I'm sure flask can send it back as a JSON object or it could just be a string.  If it's a JSON object you could access different parts of it with the . notation.  Something like msgBackFromServer.title or msgBackFromServer.message etc...

Comment: Can you please go into a little more detail what the script should look like and what the function in app.py will look like. I've never used any of these scripting languages before and not totally aware of how it all ties together. @ChrisHawkes

Comment: I updated a bit more information.  I'm not really familiar with flask though.

Comment: thank for the response. I will try and find out how to get the flask side working. Thank you for explaining it in detail too. Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

This is not AJAX.  What you seem to be trying to do is edit javascript using JINJA and send the javascript to the client. Do NOT do this.  Instead, your javascript files should be static and you should request the data itself from the flask app.

Comment: Your recommendation is to put the JavaScript in the static folder and extend it in the jinja2 template? That's not an issue to do that, I was doing it this way since I saw a tutorial doing this when I started this project. @John

Comment: My recommendation is to decouple the view elements from the data completely.  Jinja is a useful tool for HTML tempting, say dropping in an alert or a username or setting static elements- please avoid it for javascript.  You can run your AJAX queries to do state and data changes.  TBH, I rarely use jinja and instead rely on a client query to add elements or divs to a base html page